# Concurrent modification of a map during iteration

Tags: c++, iterator, erase

I have the following code:

```
std::list<std::tuple<int,double>> myList; //assume it is empty
std::map<int,double> myMap; //assume it has values
for (auto m_itr = myMap.begin(); m_itr != myMap.end();){
    myList.push_back(std::make_tuple(m_itr->first,m_itr->second));
    m_itr = myMap.erase(m_itr);
}
```

but it throws the following exception:

```
"list iterators incompatible"
```

How can I work around this exception? I want to ensure that no elements are in the map that are already in the list.

Comment: It should be `m_itr = myMap.erase(m_itr);` or `myMap.erase(m_itr++);`

Comment: How about delay `myMap.clear()` after the transformation ?

Comment: Hint: `erase` returns something. Use it.

Comment: @Slava Ok so I figure out I should do m_itr = myMap.erase(m_itr) but now I get the exception "list iterators incompatible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might simply do:

```
std::list<std::tuple<int, double>> myList(myMap.begin(), myMap.end());
myMap.clear();
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4611c913eae5f31)

else you have to use return value of `erase` to take correct iterator.

Comment: I mentioned that it didn't work but realized it was another problem and that this solution is correct.